# Which intuitive idea is captured by the definition of the successor of a natural number in terms of union : $S(n) = n \cup \{n\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Maybe an answer to this question is that we want the successor to have " one more " element than the prececessor.

Is this explanation correct?

An objection I see is that the explanation is not sufficient, since, maybe another singleton set  fused with *n* ( by union)  could have provided  this " one more" element.

So, why precisely {n} as second term of the union operation? Why not another singleton?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Because then $n$ is the set of natural elements smaller than $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to define the natural numbers such that the order will be naturally given by $\in$. I.e. we want that $n<m$ (as à number) if and only if $n \in m$ as sets. And thats the motivation to add precisely $\{n\} $ and not any other singleton.

The encoding described is known as the [Von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_ordinals).  An alternative encoding that is also valid but doesn't satisfy the above property is the [Zermelo ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals).

Comment: Please ignore my downvote, I misread what you wrote and the system won't let me undo it.

Comment: I'll answer both of your problems with one answer : We want our order to be transitive, that is we want $n\in m\in k \Rightarrow n\in k$. It is the case if we define $S(n)=n\cup\{n\} $, so the first fact you brought is wrong. It also explains why it wasn't defined by $S(n) = n\cup\{\{n\}\}$, as this definition doesnt give a transitive order.

Comment: Yes I realized that right after I wrote it, that's why I deleted it.  For some reason I was thinking of $n$ as the singleton.  If you don't mind I'd like to add a couple citations to your answer so the system will let me remove the downvote.

Comment: Im new on this forum so I dont really know how it works and what you mean by adding citations. What should I do to help you?

Comment: You don't have to do anything.  You still get all the votes because you provided the original answer and you can remove my changes if you prefer.  Also I probably shouldn't call it a citation since mathematics doesn't need a citation, more like just further reading.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to construct the natural numbers. For example, you could throw away zero and all of the even numbers and keep only ($1,3,5,\cdots$) and so on. $1$ could act as the new zero, $3$ as the new $1$, $5$ as the new $2$, and so on. As long as Peano's axioms are satisfied, the rest of arithmetic will follow. Another way to construct Peano numbers is with function composition in the sequence $\lambda$, $\lambda(\lambda)$, $\lambda(\lambda(\lambda(\cdots)))$ and so on. That construction is put to use by computer scientists in the lambda calculus.